# Can you throw a table tennis paddle?

Tags: rules, table-tennis, racket

I was playing with a friend (neither of us are particularly good) and on a shot that hit the net and went over my friend threw his paddle and managed to hit the ball back on my side and score.

I can't imagine it being very useful but would this be legal in an official table tennis match?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, this is not legal. Quoting from the [Table Tennis England Rules of the game](https://tabletennisengland.co.uk/about/rules-regs/the-basic-rules-of-table-tennis/):

> Strike – 2.5.7 – A player strikes the ball if he touches it in play with his racket, **held in the hand**, or with his racket hand below the wrist.

(my emphasis) and

> Procedure – 2.7.1 – The ball, having been served or returned, shall be struck so that it touches the opponent’s court, either directly or after touching the net assembly.

i.e. the ball must be struck in order for it to be a legal return, and a strike can happen only if the racket is held in the hand. This then results in the loss of the point:

> Conditions – 2.10.1 – Unless the rally is a let, a player shall score a point
>
> [...]
>
> Incorrect return – 2.10.1.2 – if his opponent fails to make a correct return;